# Checking if password exists and is enabled on lock screen - Android

Tags: android

Is there any way checking if you have an android lock screen password enabled on your'e device programmatically?
I started checking this using DeviceAdminReceiver and DevicePolicyManager classes but those classes do not refer to a state which is:
1.I had a password for the lock screen->I removed the password and now the password is disabled.

Thanks for the help,
Nir

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! If you find a response is helpful, please up vote it. If the response successfully answers your question, please click the green check mark next to it to accept the answer. Also please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask for advice on how to write a good question

Answer (score 1):

There's no clean way of doing this. No formal API. If you're willing to risk a hack, you can try this. I cobbled it together some code I found on this [site](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/com/android/internal/widget/LockPatternUtils.java#LockPatternUtils.0sLockPasswordFilename).

```
boolean hasPasswordOnLockScreen(){
  String sLockPasswordFilename = 
    android.os.Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + 
    "/system/password.key";
  try {
        // Check if we can read a byte from the file
        RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(filename, "r");
        raf.readByte();
        raf.close();
        return true;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
        return false;
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Note that this is a hack and has the potential to not work in the future is the path and file name of the password file changes.

Comment: this is a  bad way,I tried throws permission denied exception .It also requires root access for executing this code

Comment: Ok. Why does that make it bad? Do you know of another way that's better? I stated in my response that there is no clean, formal api for doing such a thing.

Comment: This  is bad because the system doesnt allow  to edit or read the password.key file even its an hack ,it doesn't work  but I learned a lot by searching your link.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
       public class ScreenLock {

        private static final String SYSTEM_DIRECTORY = "/system/";
        private static final String LOCK_PATTERN_FILE = "gesture.key";
        private static final String LOCK_PASSWORD_FILE = "password.key";

        public static boolean lockExists() {
            String dataSystemDirectory = Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + SYSTEM_DIRECTORY;
            String sLockPatternFilename =  dataSystemDirectory + LOCK_PATTERN_FILE;
            String sLockPasswordFilename = dataSystemDirectory + LOCK_PASSWORD_FILE;
            if (nonEmptyFileExists(sLockPatternFilename) || nonEmptyFileExists(sLockPasswordFilename)) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        private static boolean nonEmptyFileExists(String filename) {
            File file = new File(filename);
            return file.exists() && file.length() > 0;
        }

    }
```